# Getting User from processid when multiple user processes exist

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pid

I'm trying to tweak a bash script to pull back PID's of the individual application accounts when there are multiple applications running as a masterId.  This used to run under individual user accounts, but recent changes have forced the applications to all run under a combined "masterId", but still maintain a unique application Id that I can grep against.

Normally

```
pgrep -u "appId"
```

would give me a single PID.  Now I have to run:

```
pgrep -u "masterId"
```

it returns all of the PID's (each one is it's own application).

```
1234
2345
3456
```

I'm trying to come up with a command to bring me back just the PID of the appAccount(n) so I can pipe it into other useful commands.  I can do a double grep (which is closer to what I want):

```
ps aux | grep -i "masterId" | grep -i "appAccount(n)"
```

and that will get me the entire single process information, but I just want the PID to do something like:

```
ps aux | grep -i "masterId" | grep -i "appAccount(n)" | xargs sudo -u appAccount(n) kill -9
```

How do I modify the initial above command to get just the PID?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please post the output of `ps aux | grep -i "masterId" | grep -i "appAccountA"` command. There is also `pgrep -l` switch. You can filter specific index from stream using `awk`, like `awk '{print $3}'` will give you 3rd column from the input line.

Comment: I don't get it; in the 2nd case, is that `appAccount(n)` string part of the command line? its the first argument? the process name? something else? `pgrep -u masterId -if 'appAccount\(n\)'` should probably do, but your Q is so vague, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pgrep --euid "masterId" --list-full | awk '/appAccount(n)/ {print $1}'
```

Output the full process command line, then select the one with the desired account and print the first field (pid).

Comment: `awk` (just like `pgrep` btw) is using extended regular expressions; `/appAccount(n)/` will not match what you think it matches. And those kind of `ps | grep | sed | awk` pipelines are _always_ a horrible idea.

Comment: @mosvy: I interpreted the OP's "appAccount(n)" to be a placeholder, not an exact regex expression. I'm not using a regex in my `pgrep` command - I'm using a uid selector. My pipeline isn't "ps | grep | sed | awk". It has two parts - one of them is `pgrep` but it could just as easily have been `ps`. One or the other _must_ be there.

Comment: No, you could do all that in a single `pgrep` command. See my comment on the Q. But that's not clear whether the `appAccount(n)` is part of the command line or the process/thread name (`/proc/PID/comm`).

Comment: @mosvy: Sorry, I had the `--list-full` option in place so I missed the fact that it could use two criteria and only output the pid. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, you are correct.  The appAccount(n) stands for "any application identifier that runs under that masterId".